# History is not saving in the same component, with different route parameters, in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-redux, react-routing

I am working on a react js application for windows mobile. My route configuration is like below

```
<Route path='/' component={App} >
  <IndexRedirect to='/shows/1' />
  <Route path='shows/:id' onEnter={bootStrap} component={ShowsPage} />
  <Route path='settings' component={Settings} />
  <Route path='devices' component={Devices} />
</Route>
```

I have 3 tabs in the first route whose urls will be something like

```
shows/1
shows/2
shows/3
```

I am using react-router and the tabs are tabs like

```
<li key={tab}>
   <Link to={`/shows/${tab}`} className={classes.tabs} activeClassName={classes.active}>{tab}</Link>
</li>
```

**How i am navigating?**
When i run the application, the first page will be `shows/1` and if i tap on second tab, then the route will be `shows/2`.

**What's happening in browser?**
When i run the application in the browser, i can see shows/1 and if i click on second tab i can see the url is changing to `shows/2`. Here when i click the browser back button its navigating to shows/1. And when i go to settings page from `shows/2` and click on the browser back button when i am in settings page, i can see the `shows/2` page, which is perfectly alright.

**What's happening in device?**
When i run the application in the device, i can see shows/1 and if i click on second tab i can see the second tab(shows/2) content. Here when i click the device back button the **app is quitting**. And when i go to settings page from `shows/2` and click on the device back button when i am in settings page, i can see the `shows/2` page, which is perfectly alright.

**What's the issue?**
I feel that, in the device navigation is not saving if i move from one tab to another which is basically one single component.

**What i have tried?**
I tried to remove the `Link` from the tab and added a click event and in the click handler i am using the below code, but no use.

```
this.props.router.push('/shows/' + showId)
```

**What should be the behaviour?**
In device, if i navigated from `shows/1` to `shows/2`, and if i click on the device back button from the `shows/2` then i should be able to go to `shows/1` instead of quitting the app.

Any kind of help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the values of `tab` in `key={tab}` are correct?

Comment: What type of `history` are you using for your router setup?

Comment: Yes the id is unique @Ursus

Comment: Sorry, i didn't get you @ElodSzopos, what do you mean by type of history?

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the `<Router .. ` tag that wraps your individual `<Route .. ` components too? It should have a `history` attribute on there.

Comment: I didn't have the `history` attribute on it. @ElodSzopos

Comment: I tried with `history={browserHistory}` on the `Router`, but still same issue.